# AWS Amplify Authentication Issue: "Auth UserPool not configured" in a Next.js Project

Tags: next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-sam

I'm working on a **NextJS** project where I'm using **AWS Amplify** for authentication with **Amazon Cognito.** However, I'm encountering an issue where I receive an error message stating ***"Auth UserPool not configured"*** when I try to **log in/sign up.** I've checked my configurations and they seem correct, I am also able to manually create users from the **AWS GUI.** Below is the relevant code and configuration details.

***Index.js***

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify'
import { Authenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react'
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css'
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    region: process.env.REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID,
  },
})

function Home() {
  const [jwtToken, setJwtToken] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchJwtToken()
  }, [])

  const fetchJwtToken = async () => {
    try {
      const session = await Auth.currentSession()
      const token = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
      setJwtToken(token)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error fetching JWT token:', error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <Authenticator
      initialState='signIn'
      components={{
        SignUp: {
          FormFields() {
            return (
              <>
                <Authenticator.SignUp.FormFields />

                {/* Custom fields for given_name and family_name */}
                <div>
                  <label>First name</label>
                </div>
                <input
                  type='text'
                  name='given_name'
                  placeholder='Please enter your first name'
                />
                <div>
                  <label>Last name</label>
                </div>
                <input
                  type='text'
                  name='family_name'
                  placeholder='Please enter your last name'
                />
                <div>
                  <label>Email</label>
                </div>
                <input
                  type='text'
                  name='email'
                  placeholder='Please enter a valid email'
                />
              </>
            )
          },
        },
      }}
      services={{
        async validateCustomSignUp(formData) {
          if (!formData.given_name) {
            return {
              given_name: 'First Name is required',
            }
          }
          if (!formData.family_name) {
            return {
              family_name: 'Last Name is required',
            }
          }
          if (!formData.email) {
            return {
              email: 'Email is required',
            }
          }
        },
      }}
    >
      {({ signOut, user }) => (
        <div>
          Welcome {user.username}
          <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
          <h4>Your JWT token:</h4>
          {jwtToken}
        </div>
      )}
    </Authenticator>
  )
}

export default Home
```

This is the template.yaml file I ran using `sam deploy --guided` to create the infrastructure

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  template for creating the Cognito User Pool
Transform:
  - AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  Env:
    Type: String
    Default: dev

  S3BucketName:
    Type: String
    Default: pibot-nextjs-website
  CognitoUserPoolName:
    Type: String
    Default: pibot-users-v2
  CognitoWebClientName:
    Type: String
    Default: cognito-webclient

Resources:
  CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity'
    Properties:
      CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentityConfig:
        Comment: 'Origin Access Identity'

  CloudfrontDistribution:
    Type: 'AWS::CloudFront::Distribution'
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Comment: 'Cloudfront distribution for the static website'
        DefaultRootObject: 'index.html'
        Enabled: true
        HttpVersion: http2
        Origins:
          - Id: s3-website
            DomainName: !GetAtt S3Bucket.DomainName
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity:
                Fn::Sub: 'origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity}'
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          Compress: 'true'
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
          ForwardedValues:
            QueryString: false
          TargetOriginId: s3-website
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: redirect-to-https

  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub '${Env}-${S3BucketName}'

  S3BucketPolicy:
    Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
    Properties:
      Bucket: !Ref S3Bucket
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 's3:GetObject'
            Resource:
              - !Sub 'arn:aws:s3:::${S3Bucket}/*'
            Principal:
              AWS: !Sub 'arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity ${CloudFrontOriginAccessIdentity}'

  CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: !Sub '${Env}-${CognitoUserPoolName}'
      AliasAttributes:
        - email
      UsernameConfiguration:
        CaseSensitive: false
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
      Policies:
        PasswordPolicy:
          MinimumLength: 8
          RequireLowercase: true
          RequireNumbers: true
          RequireUppercase: true
          RequireSymbols: true
      Schema:
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Name: given_name
          Required: true
          StringAttributeConstraints:
            MinLength: '1'
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Name: family_name
          Required: true
          StringAttributeConstraints:
            MinLength: '1'
        - AttributeDataType: String
          Mutable: true
          Name: email
          Required: true
          StringAttributeConstraints:
            MinLength: '1'

  WebCognitoUserPoolClient:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient
    Properties:
      ClientName: !Sub '${Env}-${CognitoWebClientName}'
      UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool
      ExplicitAuthFlows:
        - ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH
        - ALLOW_REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH
      PreventUserExistenceErrors: ENABLED
```

Comment: how are you defining your environmental variables in your Next app? make sure you're doing it in the correct way: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the issue stems from the configuration setup. In AWS Amplify version 6, user pool configuration has been updated. Please adjust your configuration as follows:

```js
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      userPoolClientId: 'abcdefghij1234567890',
      userPoolId: 'us-east-1_abcd1234',
      loginWith: { // Optional
        oauth: {
          domain: 'abcdefghij1234567890-29051e27.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
          scopes: ['openid email phone profile aws.cognito.signin.user.admin '],
          redirectSignIn: ['http://localhost:3000/','https://example.com/'],
          redirectSignOut: ['http://localhost:3000/','https://example.com/'],
          responseType: 'code',
        }
        username: 'true',
        email: 'false', // Optional
        phone: 'false', // Optional
      }
    }
  }
});
```

For additional details, you can refer to the official documentation at: [AWS Amplify Documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/tools/libraries/configure-categories/#authentication-amazon-cognito)

I hope this helps resolve your issue. If you have further questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error until this afternoon. I figured out what the error is (or was is my case). I think I can see why you'd get the same error.

Like you, I was able to create new users and see them in Amplify console. However I wasn't able to log in due to that error.

You've chosen to configure amplify with the lines that you've shown. You may want to comment out that block until after you try what I suggest.

Amplify will have configured a default configuration as you've set up your authentication and answered the questions to `amplify add auth` or `amplify update auth`. This config is output to `./aws-export.js` and `./amplifyconfiguration.json`. They both have the same info, only the first is only the json without export and the second file exports the data.

The problem is that you're not using all the settings from this in your current project. To do this you need to call `Amplify.configure()` with the json like shown here: https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/set-up-auth/

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import config from './amplifyconfiguration.json';
Amplify.configure(config);
```

The best way to figure to actually do this is to create a separate file: `ConfigureAmplify.tsx` with the following contents:

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import config from "../amplifyconfiguration.json";

Amplify.configure(config, { ssr: true });

export default function ConfigureAmplifyClientSide() {
  return null;
}
```

This essentially wraps the include into a do-nothing component and allows you to use the configuration anywhere in your project. Add it to your `./src/app/page.tsx`:

```
'use client';

import type { WithAuthenticatorProps } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import { withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
import ConfigureAmplifyClientSide from '../../components/ConfigureAmplify';

export function App({ signOut, user } : WithAuthenticatorProps) {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <ConfigureAmplifyClientSide />
      <h1>Hello {user?.username}</h1>
      <button onClick={signOut}>Sign out</button>
    </main>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

I found this somewhere in the documentation. When in the right place that error should disappear. You should be able to add your current `Amplify.configure` back where you have it. You may even find it beneficial to add it to the bottom of the `ConfigureAmplify.tsx` file.

You're able to call Amplify.configure() many times to override/add/update functionality as you wish.

*In my case I was calling `Amplify.configure()` in the wrong file. I moved it and got it working "inline" however I prefer it in a separate file.*

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` for your environmental vars to make them accessible to your browser environment? https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

so your vars should be:

```
Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
   Cognito: {
    region: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_REGION,
    userPoolId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USER_POOL_ID,
    userPoolWebClientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_USER_POOL_APP_CLIENT_ID,
   }
  }
});
```

don't forget to change the var names in your .env file too :)

Also in amplify [docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/nextjs/build-a-backend/auth/set-up-auth/) userpool is configured inside `Cognito` property of `Auth` object

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was related to the configuration on "aws-exports", the Documentation is a little confusing, but I made it work with this config:

```
export const amplifyConfig = {
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      userPoolId: your_userPoolId,
      userPoolClientId: your_userPoolClientId,
      region: your_region,
      loginWith: {
        oauth: {
          domain: your_domain,
          scopes: [
            'phone',
            'email',
            'profile',
            'openid',
            'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'
          ],
          redirectSignIn: [window.location.origin],
          redirectSignOut: [window.location.origin],
          responseType: "code",
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

And also you should have something like this in you `index`

```
import { Amplify, ResourcesConfig } from "aws-amplify";
import { amplifyConfig } from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(amplifyConfig as ResourcesConfig );
```

I hope it works for you.

refs: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/12627#issuecomment-1848214340